# Remove Console Tree and Default to Standard in Services Control Panel

Tags: windows

The Windows Services control panel by default opens showing the console tree on the left and in extended mode which consumes additional space on the left.  In order to view as much information as possible the first thing I do is click the toolbar button to hide the console and click the Standard tab at the bottom and expand the name column.  I know I could do this with a macro, but I was wonder if anyone knew of a way to do any of these things automatically, perhaps with a registry change or a command line parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a command line as administrator take ownership of the services.msc:

```
takeown /f C:\Windows\System32\en-US\services.msc
cacls C:\Windows\System32\en-US\services.msc  /G Administrators:F
```

Start MMC in author mode opening the services.msc file:

```
start mmc c:\Windows\System32\en-US\services.msc /a
```

When you are done select `Save` from the `File` menu.

This works for all management consoles. just take care to

1. Use the correct folder (system32/en-us not system32).
2. Take Ownership.
3. Launch mmc in /author mode.

Comment: +1 Wow! Over a year later and you provide the permissions magic to make Evan Anderson's answer useful.

Answer (score 2):

A lightweight alternative would be to use command line equivalents(net or sc), especially if you are just restarting the same services routinely.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing you do. You can modify the %SystemRoot%\system32\services.msc file to open in the view you want, but you'll need to do that for ever machine you're opening that file on.

Comment: OK, I found how to turn the Console Tree off by setting ScopePaneVisible="false", but I haven't found how to switch from Extended to Standard.

Comment: Oh! You're editing the raw XML file. I just re-saved "services.msc" after opening it with MMC. Based on comparing two different versions of the same base file (with the view toggled differently but otherwise identical), I'm not seeing exactly how the Standard / Extended status is stored. I'm having success, though, using an "services.msc" that's been opened w/ MMC, modified, and re-saved. I'd give that a shot before getting too bogged down in the XML.

Comment: I didn't know you could edit the XML using the GUI, but it looks like you can.  I copied the services.msc file and opened the copy by right clicking on it and choosing "Author".  I then made all the changes I wanted then choose save from the file menu.  This works great except that I have to launch my copy.  I haven't figured out yet how to replace the original services.msc.